Error: <component> not found in '@chakra-ui/react' import/named, nextjs
I'm building a nextjs app with chakra-ui and typescript
I'm using "next": "13.1.1", @chakra-ui/icons": "^2.0.17", "@types/node": "18.15.11", "@types/testing-library__react": "^10.2.0", "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.1", "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.1"
When running next build I keep getting this error: Error: AlertStatus not found in '@chakra-ui/react'  import/named, with a series of different chakra components, not only AlertStatus.
I tried upgrading/downgrading versions of chakra, nothing seems to work

AlertStatus doesnt seem to be exported? Do you mean <Alert status="">? https://v2.chakra-ui.com/docs/components/alert/usage#import
